# Regular expression not tracing whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to validate the phone number. Its not specific to any country, Its my requirement.

My requirement:

1. Phone number is not mandatory (can be left blank, without filling)
2. should not contain white spaces inbetween ex: 12 123
3. should not be completely filled with white spaces

I could satisfy the first two conditions with the below code. 3rd one I cant trap in regex.

I have the following code:

```
    final String regEx = "^[^\\s][-+()0-9]{1,20}$";

    if (phoneNumber1 != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber1) && (!phoneNumber1.matches(regEx)))
    {
        //error message
    }
```

can you help me to track if it contains white spaces?

Comment: Code tip: assuming you are using `StringUtils` from Apache `commons-lang` (or `commons-lang3`), you can replace `if (phoneNumber1 != null) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber1) ...` with `if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber1) ...`. `StringUtils` considers `null` strings to be empty.

Comment: `!StringUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber1.trim())` ?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the choice between two non-capturing groups. The first one is an empty string `^$` surrounded with non-capturing group `(?:^$)`. Then the alternation operator `|` and at least one digit (\d+) in the second non-capturing group `(?:\d+)`. All captured gives the result:

```
((?:^$)|(?:\d+))
```

Check the detailed explanation out: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pY0cB8/1)

In Java, it looks like here:

```
String s[] = {"123456", "", "123 456"};
for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(s[i].matches("((?:^$)|(?:\\d+))"));
}
```

> true
>   true
>   false

Answer (score 0):

If the max is 20 digits, you could try:

```
 String[] phoneNumbers = new String[]{"", "          ", "123 456", "123456"};
 for (String p: phoneNumbers){
     System.out.println( p.matches("^[0-9]{0,20}$") + " => " + p);
 }
```

Output:

```
true =>           //blank phone number
false =>          //phone number completely filled with white spaces         
false => 123 456
true => 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would create a regex for all whitespaces (e.g. "\s+") and check that it *doesn't* match.  It's can be fun to try to figure out a single regex for all these things but there's nothing requiring that and you will save a ton of time by keeping it simple.

On a side note, I hate it when rules like this are put on telephone numbers.  just strip out all the non-numeric characters.  Why do you care whether the user enters semantically unimportant formatting?  It's really helpful to the user to avoid typos.

Comment: Hi.. I am facing an issue here. I read two values from console. if the console is filled with whitespaces or if it is left blank, in both cases i read the input as null in java program. Thats the reason why my logic is failing at first check in the IF condition and is not proceeding further!!

Comment: I think this depends on how you are reading in the input.  Since you haven't provided the code I can only guess at the problem.  One quick suggestion is to check for null before doing anything else.

Comment: Exactly James.. I see the problem in reading input. Here is my code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the code.  That sounds like a different issue so you should probably create a separate question.